# Multiple dropdown menus, one JQuery script

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

I have been playing with the jDiv dropdown menu developed by Skyrocket Labs and improved by Peter Hinton.  It works well for multiple menus on the same page, as long as you replicate the code with different identifiers (#nav1 triggers #hidden-menu1, #nav2 triggers #hidden-nav2, etc).

```
        var hide1 = false;
$("#nav1").hover(function(){          
    if (hide1) clearTimeout(hide1);
    $("#hidden-nav1").show();
    }, function() {
    hide1 = setTimeout(function() {$("#hidden-nav1").hide();});
    });

    $("#hidden-nav1").hover(function(){
    if (hide1) clearTimeout(hide1);
    }, function() {
    hide1 = setTimeout(function() {$("#hidden-nav1").hide();});
    $("#hidden-nav1").stop().show();
    });
```

I am trying to sort out how to rewrite the code so that it can, "discover" the numerical value of the navX linked hovered and trigger the appropriate hidden-navX divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working
[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/77CXH/)

I removed ALL ID's just to show how easy and striped can be the code and functional too, just using *classes*.

You can undo your ID's if you need to use them, but leave all unchanged.

If you need explanation about the code I can comment each line.

Here is the new/changed Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var countNavs = 0; $('#navlist li').attr('class', function() {countNavs++;return 'connected' + countNavs;});
    var countDrops = 0; $('.dropdown').attr('class', function() {countDrops++;return 'dropdown connected' + countDrops;});

    var hide1 = false;            
    $("#navlist li").hover(function(){    
        var equal = $(this).attr('class');

        $('.active').removeClass();
    if (hide1) clearTimeout(hide1);
        $('.dropdown').hide();
        $('.'+equal).not('li').show();
        $(this).children('a').toggleClass('active');                
    }, function() {
        hide1 = setTimeout(function() {$('.'+equal).not('li').hide();});
    });

    $('.dropdown').hover(function(){        
        if (hide1) clearTimeout(hide1);            
    }, function() {            
        hide1 = setTimeout(function() {$('.dropdown').hide();});
        $('.active').removeClass();        
        $('.dropdown').stop().show();
    });

});
```

With [COMMENTS](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/77CXH/1/)

To help you understand in few words: We add automatically a SAME custom class to each 'li' and his corespondent 'dropdown' called: '.connectedN',
 where 'N' is an incremented number.
 Than we just say: if the hovered 'li' is class 'connected3' that means we just hovered the 3th 'li' , and we'll go to open the '.dropdown' that have the SAME class.

Comment: Thanks for that, but we have a fairly extensive flyout menu currently being used and I am trying to simplify and reduce the code size at the moment.

Comment: Exactly that. This 4 lines of code can handle hundreds of infinite :) number of menus. I just want to show you the base functionality. The principle is that the mouse activates THIS action element. all the rest is nested to that element .childrens or .next and so on

Comment: @roXon, thanks for that.  The jDiv function is nice in that it uses two separate divs to keep the triggers and targets separate, whereas your example using lists puts it all together.  With the separate divs aspect I can move the bulk of the navigation code to the bottom of the file and out of search bots way, thus pushing the content higher up in the file.  Also allows me to strip the navigation code out of the main file and add it in via JQuery's load function, thus allowing a quicker initial load.

Comment: That is why I was trying simply to reduce the amount of code for jDiv, but I haven't been able to get @Raynos version to function.

Comment: I was not able to Google for jDiv cause looks like it has been moved / closed. So I can't have an idea... a picture of what is about. Do you have a link?

Comment: The original developer has closed his website, but an example from Peter Hinton is still available: http://www.peterhintondesign.co.uk/journal/index.php/using-multiple-instances-of-jdiv/

Comment: @Tom Look above for the RE-EDITED answer.

Comment: @roXon It looks good, but I am heading out the door for a meeting, so can't play with it too much at the moment.  Will get after it I get back.

Comment: @roXon,  Thanks that works well.  You mentioned maybe commenting the code, that would be nice to help learn why you did what you did. :)

Comment: @roXon ... thanks once again, the comment help much with understanding.  Will also help me modify the script to fit our particular layout.  Can't use li for our triggers because we want to change the z-index for the active trigger so that it floats over the flyout panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function doNav(id) {
    var hide = false;
    $(id).hover(function() {
        if (hide) clearTimeout(hide);
        $("#hidden" + id).show();
    }, function() {
        hide = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#hidden" + id).hide();
        });
    });

    $("#hidden" + id).hover(function() {
        if (hide) clearTimeout(hide);
    }, function() {
        hide = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#hidden" + id).hide();
        });
        $("#hidden" + id).stop().show();
    });
}

for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    doNav("nav" + i);
}
```

Comment: The hide1 changes as well.  Hovering over #nav2, would need to update the ending values to nav2, hidden-nav2, hide2, etc.

Comment: @Tom You call this functions for each nav. They all use a local `hide` variable.

Comment: OK, so do I simply add extra doNav for each trigger ?  ie: `doNav("nav2"); doNav("nav3");`

Comment: @Tom pretty much. You can use an array. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Tom if it solves your question, please do click the checkmark next to my answer ;)

Comment: @Raynos - can't seem to get it to work.  There seems to be a { missing, which i am guessing goes after the function doNav(id)  But even with that it doesn't want to work.